# Why did they have armed prototype robots in a Skynet facility?

Tags: the-terminator-series, skynet, terminator-3-rise-of-the-machines

One reason why they couldn't stop Skynet (aside from Governator stating it was inevitable), was that all the employees and military in the building, including the General, got killed - mostly by TX-nanoinfected robots who proceeded with massacring everyone and nearly killed John and his GF

So... why would those robots be armed with loaded weapons, in a military base (when in reality, soldiers not on guard duty never ever have access to loaded weapons, and there are incredibly tight rules on live ammunition).

I'm looking for canon based answer (films/series/books/interviews with creators), not a guess.

Comment: Mayhaps the military personnel *thought* they were unarmed, but in reality they had real ammunition because, you know, Skynet.

Answer (score 3):

IIRC the military base was an R&D facility where the prototype drone systems (including the drones themselves and automated rearm and repair facilities) it stands to reason that the facility was involved in live fire testing of the drone weapons and had systems in place to arm the drones when required

I dont know if we ever see rearm and repair facilities in canon however